# how to print array of the array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
I have 2 -d array p[i][j] by using 

    for (int jj=0; jj < N;jj++){

            My_0[jj] = p[0][jj]; 
            My_1[jj] = p[1][jj];
            My_2[jj] = p[2][jj]; 
            My_3[jj] = p[3][jj]; 
            My_4[jj] = p[4][jj];
            My_5[jj] = p[5][jj]; 
            My_6[jj] = p[6][jj]; 
            My_7[jj] = p[7][jj];
            My_8[jj] = p[8][jj];
            My_9[jj] = p[9][jj]; 

    }
I extracted rows from p and inserted into My_0 to My_9 one by one,,,then I inserted each My_0 to My_9 into a arraylist class object 

    List<AA> part = new ArrayList<AA>();
    AA newP = new AA(); 

    // using
    newP.setO(My_0);
    newP.setO(My_1);
    newP.setO(My_2);
    newP.setO(My_3);
    newP.setO(My_4);
    newP.setO(My_5);
    newP.setO(My_6);
    newP.setO(My_7);
    newP.setO(My_8);
    newP.setO(My_9);

    part.add(newP);
    // then print this array list using

    System.out.println("Size === "+ part.size());
    for (int j1=0; j1 < part.size();j1++) {
        System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString((part).get(j1).getO()));
    }
```

but the problem is it is only printing the My_9 array upto part.size().what should i do to print all My_0 to My_9.

```
           newP0.setO(My_0);
           newP1.setO(My_1); //like this done for every My_0 to My_9
           part.add(newP0);
           part.add(newP1); //like this done for every My_0 to My_9

         System.out.println("Size === "+ part.size());
          for (int j1=0; j1 < part.size();j1++){
          System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString((part).get(j1).getO()));
```

and i'm using the above code for printing part it will print size=100 and print My_0 to My_9 values 10 times,is it correct or code is going wrong while printing,,i think it should only print My_0 to My_9 values one time only

Comment: Could you try to format your question, indent the code and post a [mcve] ? You have text in the code block, that's not helping. You have variable that we don't see the declaration ( `My_9`, that's not a standard syntax by the way).

Answer (score 1):

It is only printing your My_9 because you are setting `newP.setO(My_..)` which is always overriding the previous value of `O`.

`newP.setO(My_9)`  is the last set you do on newP, meaning that `O` has My_9 value.

```
// using
newP.setO(My_0); // o is now equal to My_0
newP.setO(My_1); // o is now equal to My_1
newP.setO(My_2); // o is now equal to My_2 
...
```

Maybe what you want to do is to create a new `AA` object, give it the `My_xx` you want, add it to `part` and then do it again for the next `My_..` you have.

Like this:

```
 AA newP0 = new AA();
 newP0.setO(My_0);
 part.add(newP0);

 AA newP1 = new AA();
 newP1.setO(My_1);
 part.add(newP1);
```

And also, as mentioned in comment your are doing `Arrays.toString((part).get(ii)` but you have declare `j1` in your for loop.

```
for (int j1=0; j1 < parti.size();j1++) {
    System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString((part).get(ii).getO()));
}
```

You also see that `parti` should be `part` in the for loop declaration.

To be honest I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this. We lack a lot of informations, like what's `AA` ? And you should consider using [Camel casing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for your variables.

Comment: You can add the fact that the loop is using `int j1` but in the block, you find `get(ii)`.

Comment: Yep, there is a lot of weird stuff in this code. But I'll add this to my answer, thanks

Comment: The condition is using another list ( `parti.size()`, instead of `part.size()`, typo or not).

Comment: newP0.setO(My_0);
               newP1.setO(My_1); like this done for every My_0 to My_9
               part.add(newP0);
               part.add(newP1); like this done for every My_0 to My_9

             System.out.println("Size === "+ part.size());
              for (int j1=0; j1 < part.size();j1++){
              System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString((part).get(j1).getO()));
              }

Comment: and i'm using the above code for printing part it will print size=100 and print My_0 to My_9 values 10 times,  
            is it correct or code is going wrong while printing,,i think it should only print My_0 to My_9 values one time only

Comment: Thanks Kevyn Meganck,